# INFO log is not displaying in Console on Spark Submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I use the below command to submit my spark standalone application.

```
/Users/chitti/spark/bin/spark-submit --jars $(echo /Users/chitti/phoenix/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')  --class "SimpleApp"  --master local[2] target/scala-2.10/appproject_2.10-1.0.jar
```

But I dont get any INFO messages, as I need to debug my application.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check your `/Users/chitti/spark/conf/log4j.properties` and see the logging level for `log4j.rootCategory` and any other `org.apache.spark` loggers?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski the log4j.rootCategory is set to "INFO, console".

Comment: What's the Spark version? Can you paste the entire output from the moment you execute `spark-submit`? Edit your question and paste there. Remove `--master local[2]` as it's not really needed.

Comment: Can you also execute `./bin/run-example SparkPi` and see if that prints any output?